# Determine if a URL returned by ServletContext.getResource() represents a folder or a file

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have a war, with a single servlet that is mapped to /*. I want to serve some static resources stored in the WAR, so I should use [ServletContext.getResource()][1] to retrieve the resources from the WAR right?

I have noticed one problem though with using getResource(). It does not seem possible to reliably determine if the URL returned represents a resource with content or is just a folder resource (a container for other resources), in a way that works across ALL Java EE containers.

Let's take an example, say this is the contents of WAR

+
|
+-hello.html
+-folder/
|  |
|  +-world.html
|
+-folder2/
|  |
|  +-index.html
|
+-WEB-INF/

and this WAR is deployed with a context-path of: /test

I want to make hello.html accessible at http://example.com/test/hello.html
I want to make world.html accessible at http://example.com/test/folder/world.html
I do not want http://example.com/test/folder/ to be accessible (I want to generate a 403 response for that URL)
For the URL http://example.com/test/folder2/ I want to display the contents of index.html
For the URL http://example.com/test/folder I want to redirect to http://example.com/test/folder/
For the URL http://example.com/test/folder/index.html I want to redirect to http://example.com/test/folder/

On Tomcat and Glassfish if I do:

ServletContext.getResource('folder/') I will get back a URL, if I attempt to open that URL's stream I'll get a FileNotFoundException, a bit crazy but OK it tells me the resource is a folder (exists but not found == folder).

On Weblogic (and OC4J) I get back a plain text stream , listing the files within the folder. Which is not good if you don't want to leak the raw contents of the folder for any reason.

It gets messier on TC/GF if I do:

ServletContext.getResource('folder') I get the same result as ServletContext.getResource('folder/'). Even weirder if I do ServletContext.getResource('folder/hello.html') I still get back a URL but then get a FileNotFoundException when trying to open the stream.

What am I missing? this seems like a basic need (to be able to tell if a resource represents a folder or a file), yet I can see no reliable cross Java EE container method to do this. Should I just use ClassLoader.getResource() instead ?

[1] http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 0):

This is what's known as 'undefined behavior', left as an exercise for the container vendor. The resource is not, in fact, a File, it's a jar resource.

So, I'd suggest that to accomplish what you want, you'll probably need to store your file hierarchy in the file system, rather than in the war file, and access them via the File api.